# Handling circular associations when destroying an ActiveRecord object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have some Rails 4 ActiveRecord models that are organized as follows

[image]

Assume everything is a `has_many` relationship, and is set with `dependent: :destroy`

- A `User` has many `Items`
- An `Item` has many `Tags`
- A `Tag` has many `Foos`
- A `User` has many `Foos`

When I delete a particular `User` record, it will correctly kick off the chain of destruction and delete the associated `Item`, `Tag`, and `Foo` records.

But it will also try to directly destroy `Foo`.

Will there be a race condition here? Will it error out depending on which model gets there "first". Either one of `User` or `Tag` are going to see the record already deleted when it tries to run the `DELETE` statement.

If so, how can I prevent this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have the "destroy" parameter in the "User has many Foos" relationship.

"Foo" must be destroyed by "Tag" using "User.destroy_all".